# Python Flask: How to stop the user from exploiting Inspect Element or to get rid of the possibility completely

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a chat website using python Flask. I have a route called '/chatroom', and every time a message is sent (using the HTML I'm returning in the function), the HTML also sends along a hidden field with the value of the userid back to the start of the chatroom so I can use the request.args.get function to get the userid. My problem is that anyone on the site can simply Inspect Element and change their user id located in the hidden field to get past my user removal method. Is there a way to check if Inspect Element is used by any client or to disable it? Or better yet, is it possible to not have to send the user id along in the hidden field? Here is the code for the message send field and the userid hidden field:

```
`'''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action='/chatroom'>
<input type=text name='msg'>
<input type=hidden name=userid value="''',userid,'''">
</form>
</body>
</html>'''`
```

Every time the form is sent, like I said earlier, the program gets the 'userid' argument and assigns in to the variable userid.

I have a different method about the first time when the page loads. Just ignore that for now.

Thanks!

P.S. If the question feels vague, which it probably will, just comment on this and I can clear it up.

Comment: why not use sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not really with Inspect Element - the problem is that you've built a site which is, unfortunately, insecure.

One way of handling this would be to encode and decode user IDs with each communication between the client and server. So the `userid` that is sent forward to the frontend (the client) is encoded and no longer looks like a regular user ID. Then when the request is sent to the server, the server decodes the ID to be able to identify the user.

This is a very simplified version of web security and isn't even close to foolproof; for example, what's to stop people just copying the encoded IDs? You could follow it up by hashing IDs, but that adds more complexity. Long story short, it's going to be touch to implement yourself, and disabling Inspect Element won't solve the problem of your site being insecure. As such, I suggest that you look into existing packages which aim to secure user identities and either use them out of the box or try to replicate their behaviour. A couple of examples to investigate are [Sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/category/sessions/) and [Security](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/category/security/) - thery would be good places to start.